# Find process by thread ID

Tags: windows-7, windows, batch, process

One of my programs outputs its thread ID for debugging purposes. For testing reasons I'd like to kill the process to which the thread ID belongs.

**How do I get the process ID if I have the thread ID so that I can use it with `taskkill`?**

I tried

- `tasklist` but it doesn't seem to have a switch for thead IDs.
- SysInternals [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653)'s "Find handle" feature, which works, but I'd need something that can be automated in a batch file
- SysInternals [Handle](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) `-a Thread`, but that doesn't seem to work. `handle -a | find "Thread"` works better, but I lose the process information

Comment: Are you willing to write a bit of code for this (like, C++ or C#)? The API you would call is [GetProcessIdOfThread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683216(v=vs.85).aspx), which needs a thread HANDLE; you would get that by calling [OpenThread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684335(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @CBHacking: well, if necesary... I thought it must exist out of the box already.

Comment: I mean, yeah, I'm sure it can be done using sufficiently convoluted regular expressions with `findstr` or similar. But yeah, tools for Windows don't generally assume you are trying to go from thread ID to process ID; it's usually the other way around.

Comment: @CBHacking: No, for sure, if a tool like `tid2pid` does not exist, I'd rather write one

Comment: @CBHacking: are you familiar with C++? I added a solution which seems to work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this with a batch file:

Batchfile killprocess.bat:

```
@echo off
set processhandle=
set description=
set handle=%1
IF "%handle%." == "." (
  echo Usage: killprocess threadID
  exit/b
)

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('WMIC PATH Win32_thread WHERE handle^=%handle% GET Processhandle /VALUE ^| find "="') DO set "%%A"
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('WMIC PATH Win32_process WHERE handle^=%processhandle% GET Description /VALUE ^| find "="') DO set "%%A"

IF "%ProcessHandle%." == "." (
  echo ThreadID not found
  exit/b
)

echo I'm going to kill %Description% (Processhandle = %processhandle%) if you don't press Q in 5 seconds
echo (or you can press Y to continue)
choice /N /T 5 /C yq /D y
if "%errorlevel%"=="2" goto :eof

echo Killing %Description% (Processhandle = %processhandle%)
Taskkill /PID %processhandle% /T /F
```

Usage would be something like this:
`killprocess 13008`

Edit: I also added an abort option (choice) and a description of the process being killed. You could delete this if you don't want it.

Comment: Edit: I also added an abort option (choice) and a description of the process being killed. You could delete this if you don't want it.

Comment: Great. That works. You were faster than me implementing a C++ solution.

Comment: Nice solution ;)

Comment: It's possible to `DO set "%%A"` ? I don't understand how you can call this variable as value

Comment: @Paul `%%A` contains the complete line `ProcessHandle=xxxx` which wmic returns. So `DO set %%AA` will be substituted in `DO set ProcessHandle=xxxx` which works perfectly. (That way you don't have to split the output of wmic into ProcessHandle and the actual value :))

Answer (score 0):

Here's my C++ solution in case anyone wants to use it, I license it as CC0 / public domain. I seldom implement in C++, so forgive mistakes.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <sstream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        std::cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " <Thread ID>" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Returns the process ID of a thread." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Errorlevels:" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "   0 success" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "   1 too few arguments" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "   2 error parsing thread ID" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "   3 error opening thread" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::istringstream iss(argv[1]);
    int threadId;

    if (iss >> threadId)
    {
        std::cout << threadId << std::endl;
        HANDLE threadHandle = OpenThread(THREAD_QUERY_INFORMATION, false, (DWORD)threadId);
        if (threadHandle)
        {
            DWORD pid = GetProcessIdOfThread(threadHandle);
            CloseHandle(threadHandle);
            std::cout << pid << std::endl;
            return 0;
        }
        std::cerr << "Error opening thread. Perhaps run as admin or thread does not exist?";
        return 3;
    }
    std::cerr << "Error parsing thread ID. Use decimal, not hex?";
    return 2;
}
```

Comment: This looks good, yes. The C++ stream silliness (overloading the bit-shift operators) will probably always bother me, but the code appears correct. Could be a little more robust and have better error reporting (for example, check `GetLastError()` when something goes wrong) but it should work fine.